# Allow all characters in Android app

Tags: android, character, special-characters

I am helping to develop an app for Android that uses special characters from different parts of the world at times, specifically when listing the names of people. So, a good example would be a Spanish or Swedish accent on a name. The app is not rendering these correctly. What do I need to add to web services so that these accent marks show correctly? They show correctly in my database, but not in the app.

Comment: Needs more info. What have you tried and what's going wrong? If I had to take a shot in the dark, I'd say that the text is being entered or displayed using the wrong encoding. You should just be using Unicode (UTF-8) for everything, as that encoding covers all the characters you're likely to want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

```
String original;
original = new String("A" + "\u00ea" + "\u00f1" + "\u00fc" + "C");
```

> When printed, the String named `original` appears as:
>
> **`AêñüC`**
>
> To convert the String object to UTF-8, invoke the **getBytes**
>   method and specify the appropriate **encoding as a parameter**.
>   The getBytes method returns an array of bytes in UTF-8 format. To
>   create a String object from an array of non-Unicode bytes, invoke the
>   String constructor with the encoding parameter. The code that makes
>   these calls is enclosed in a try block, in case the specified encoding
>   is unsupported:

```
try {
     byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
     byte[] defaultBytes = original.getBytes(); 
     String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
     System.out.println("roundTrip = " + roundTrip);
     System.out.println();
     printBytes(utf8Bytes, "utf8Bytes");
     System.out.println();
     printBytes(defaultBytes, "defaultBytes"); 
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); 
     }
```

> The StringConverter program prints out the values in the utf8Bytes and defaultBytes arrays to demonstrate an
>   important point: The length of the converted text might not be the
>   same as the length of the source text. Some Unicode characters
>   translate into single bytes, others into pairs or triplets of bytes.